# RegEx to cut out URL

Tags: regex

I try to get an URL from a String of the following format:

RANDOMRUBBISHhttps://www.my-url.com/randomfirstname_randomlastnameRANDOMRUBBISH

I already tried some things, especially the the look before/after, which I used before successfully on another url format (starts https... ends .html, this was working).

But seems I'm too stupid to figure out the regex for the kind of string mentioned above. I just want the URL part from https.... to the end of the random last name. Is this even possible?

Any Ideas?

Comment: Will the random rubbish always appear in capitals after the last name? What differentiates the continuation of a last name and the random rubbish?

Comment: `https://www.my-url.com/randomfirstname_randomlastnameRANDOMRUBBISH` i don't see any reason why this can't be a URL.

Comment: `https\:\/\/.+_randomlastname` should do.

Comment: There has to be *something* to mark the end of the URL or the beginning of RANDOMRUBBISH otherwise its impossible to distinguish some forms of RANDOMRUBBISH from being part of the URL.

Comment: No I just wrote this uppercase to show what I want to get out of the string. Should have been more clear on that.

I don't think there is any special marker at the end of the URL, if so, my try with look before would have worked in any way. (like in the URLs I got working which ended .html, that was easy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can guarantee that randomfirstname_randomlastname is all lowercase and RANDOMRUBBISH is all uppercase, you can use character classes [a-z] and [A-Z].  The language the regex is for will determine how to use these.

This is example works in javascript:

```
var str = "RANDOMRUBBISHhttps://www.my-url.com/randomfirstname_randomlastnameRANDOMRUBBISH"; 
var match = /https:\/\/www\.my-url\.com\/[a-z]*/.exec(str);
```

Comment: Ok sry I should have been more clear on this. The RANDOM part is not all uppercase, it should just show the difference to what I want to get out of the string.

Comment: There either needs to be some way to tell when the last name ends, or if there is a known list of last names, a dictionary matching algorithm could take everything after .com/ and compare substrings beginning at character 0 with the known last names, but even then, you run the risk of last names smith, smithers and smithersly all matching the string.  When this happens, you _could_ use the longest matching last name.